# Trying to understand vector Jacobian product with higher order derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, jacobian

I am trying to understand in mathematical terms how derivatives are computed using automatic differentiation tools like `PyTorch`. I am focusing [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/autogradqs_tutorial.html#optional-reading-tensor-gradients-and-jacobian-products). I started with a simple example when $f\colon \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^N$

\begin{align*}
f\colon \mathbb{R}^N & \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^N\\
x&\longmapsto [x_1^2, \dots, x_N^2]^T,
\end{align*} Then, the Jacobian of $f$ is

$$J = \begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_N}\\
    \vdots                             & \ddots & \vdots\\
    \dfrac{\partial f_N}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial f_N}{\partial x_N}
\end{bmatrix} = 2\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & x_2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & x_3 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & x_N \end{bmatrix}_{N\times N}$$ and the vector Jacobian product is $v^TJ = 2[x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n]$, where $v = [1, 1, \dots, 1]^T$. Now I am trying to understand how $v^TJ$ is computed when

\begin{align*}
f\colon \mathbb{R}^{N\times N} & \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}\\
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & \cdots & x_{1N} \\
x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} & \cdots & x_{2N} \\
x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33} & \cdots & x_{3N} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_{N1} & x_{N2} & 0 & \cdots & x_{NN} \end{bmatrix}&\longmapsto \begin{bmatrix}
x_{11}^2 & x_{12}^2 & x_{13}^2 & \cdots & x_{1N}^2 \\
x_{21}^2 & x_{22}^2 & x_{23}^2 & \cdots & x_{2N}^2 \\
x_{31}^2 & x_{32}^2 & x_{33}^2 & \cdots & x_{3N}^2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_{N1}^2 & x_{N2}^2 & x_{N3}^2 & \cdots & x_{NN}^2 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*} An practical example is given [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/autogradqs_tutorial.html#optional-reading-tensor-gradients-and-jacobian-products). Could you please some one explain in mathematical terms how $v^TJ$ is computed in this case where $v$ is a ``vector'' of all ones?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Jacobian-vector product"? This is not standard mathematical terminology.

Comment: @AlexProvost Sorry, this is how I met it in machine learning libraries and blogs. What I mean is described in the example. If there is a strict mathematical definition I am glad to hear it! Thanks for the response.

Comment: You have not defined a function from $\Bbb R^{N\times N}$ to $\Bbb R^{N\times N}$. You have only defined the function on diagonal matrices (with values again in diagonal matrices), so this is still a function from $\Bbb R^N$ to $\Bbb R^N$. If you really want a function on $\Bbb R^{N\times N}$, you have to specify the value of the function on an arbitrary $N\times N$ matrix.

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks for the comment. I did a change. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Without talking about tensors here, I would recommend encoding your matrices a vectors with $N^2$ entries, and then this is exactly like your first example (with $N^2$ in place of $N$).

Answer (score 1):

In the language of `pytorch` you can flatten your input and output tensor and thinking about a map from $f\colon \mathbb{R}^{N^2}  \to\mathbb{R}^{N^2}$.

Then your Jacobian is still a giant matrix of $\mathbb{R}^{N^2\times N^2}$.
Just like your vector example, the entries of the matrix have no interaction, so the Jacobian is a diagonal matrix, just like your example above.

Then given a vector $v=[v_{11},v_{12},...v_{NN-1},v_{NN}]$ of $N^2$ entries, multiplying it by the diagonal Jacobian is just element-wise multiplication.
$$
v^TJ = 2[x_{11}v_{11},x_{12}v_{12},...x_{NN-1}v_{NN-1},x_{NN}v_{NN}]
$$
Then you can easily `reshape` this vector jacobian product into $N,N$ matrix.